# Is there a keyboard shortcut to cycle through all the applications in mission control in macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, mission-control

I want to use keyboard to switch between apps in mission control.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to cycle through all the applications in mission control in macOS?

Answer (score 2):

There is no keyboard shortcut to switch between applications within Mission Control,
as can be seen in *System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control*,
where you can see all of the built in keyboard shortcuts available,
but none of which allows moving between applications in a space.

Mission Control is designed to be used with a mouse or trackpad.
If you only use the keyboard, use instead <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
to switch between apps.

You could try to use
[Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org)
to solve to this problem.
Once you install it, you can use the lua code supplied in the
[documentation](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.expose.html)
to get started.

Once invoked through a shortcut of your liking, it assigns and displays a keycode
to each of the open windows inside expose/mission control, and
you may set filters and customize it further.

Source:
[Keyboard shortcut to switch between applications in Mission Control](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127240/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-applications-in-mission-control).